# Advice on moving CiviCRM Configuration only when launching a new site

Tags: configuration

Can anyone shed some light on the best way to move CiviCRM settings only when launching a new site.

Essentially we want to be able to launch our Drupal 7 CiviCRM 4.6.9 (as of today) like a one click install. We work with specific clients from similar industries who usually have a similar requirements.

For example, we create 3 profile types, turn off 3 components for CiviCRM, Add the tax rate,create a responsive email template and setup the look and feel for events using a custom template.

Is it as simple as setting this up on a test site and copying the civicrm.settings files to the new site each time? or is there a better way to do this and not having to update the Resource URLs each time and the views configuration.

Thanks.

Comment: We looked at this recently (see http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/6652/149) and did some work to export entities to .yml for transfer between sites (see https://github.com/xurizaemon/civicrm-configexport, not a complete solution).